# Placing three tables next to each other

Tags: tables, pdftex

I am trying to place three tables next to each other. Because they have the same caption, they are placed in three tabular envs in the same table env. For positioning I use minipage.

This works fairly well, but when looking closely, the gaps between tables 1/2 and 2/3 are not exactly the same width. This looks annoying with longer tables. Any ideas about how to get those gaps exactly the same width? The overall table should stay centered.

I actually use this in a large document with lots of packages loaded, but the behaviour seems to be the same in this MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}        
\begin{document}        
        \begin{table}
            \footnotesize
                \begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
                \raggedright
                \begin{tabular}{|p{3.2cm}|c|}
                    \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                \end{tabular}
                \end{minipage}
                \begin{minipage}[c]{0.33\textwidth}
                %\centering
                \begin{tabular}{|p{3.2cm}|c|}
                    \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                \end{tabular}
                \end{minipage}%
                \begin{minipage}[c]{0.33\textwidth}
                %\raggedleft
                \begin{tabular}{|p{3.2cm}|c|}
                    \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                \end{tabular}
                \end{minipage}
                \caption{99 most frequent hashtags in the data set.}
            \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Difference is because you didn't put after first minipage `%` as after second one. Add this `%` after first minipage or erase one after second minipage.

Comment: You are right, this works in the MWE. In my actual code it does not. There it makes the gap difference even wider. (strange)

Comment: because you in the first and last minipages use `˛\raggedright` and in center one nothing. If you put in all three minipages `\centering`, then both gaps become equal. After all, far more simple solution you receive in @AboAmmar answer.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I think I actually tried all of those things in my actual document and nothing seemed to work properly. But maybe this is caused by some package or other. thank you anyway

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

No need for `minipage`s, `\raggedright` or any extra stuff. Just `tabular`s and `\hfill` between any two of them. The placement option `[t]` also aligns the tables' headers.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}        
\begin{document}        
        \begin{table}
            \footnotesize
                \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{3.2cm}|c|}
                    \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                \end{tabular}
                \hfill
                \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{3.2cm}|c|}
                    \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                \end{tabular}
                \hfill
                \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{3.2cm}|c|}
                    \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                    bla&1\\ \hline
                    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{99 most frequent hashtags in the data set.}
            \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I know how to modify your code if I want to have caption of each sub-tables?

Comment: If this doesn't work, it might be because the tables are too wide.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway if somebody is interested to know how to make subcaption for each table here the code. As Trevin Avery says in the remarks that I forgot to precise it requires the package `\usepackage{subcaption}` :

```
\begin{table}
\subcaptionbox{caption A}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}
}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{caption B}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}
}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{caption C}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
    bla&1\\ \hline
    blubb&2 \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}
}
\hfill
\caption{99 most frequent hashtags in the data set.}
\end{table}
```

I really Thank AboAmmar for his help to build this solution

Comment: This requires `\usepackage{subcaption}` in the preamble. You can see the additional options in the [docs](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf).

Comment: Yes you're right it requires this package. Thanks for the precision for anyone who need. I will notice in the main post.