# Tables in a row

Tags: tables

I have three tables and I'm planning to organize them next to each other. I tried the code in  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260888/placing-three-tables-next-to-each-other) but I couldn't even see any result!!

could someone advice me how to solve this issue?!

Thanks

```
 \begin{table}
                    \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\

        \hline
         1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\

         2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\

         3 & D3& NR& \\

         4 &  D5 &R& $0.75$\\

         5 & D1 &R& $0.8$ \\

         6 & D6 &NR&  \\

         7 &  D12 &R& $0.71$\\

         8 & D15 &NR& \\

         9 & D21 &NR& \\

         10 & D9 &R& $0.6$ \\
          \hline
         \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Avg}} & $0.810$ \\
         \hline
        \end{tabular}
                        \hfill
        \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{Query Q2}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\

        \hline
         1 & D2 & R & $1.00$\\

         2 &  D1 & NR&\\

         3 & D3& NR& \\

         4 &  D5 &R& $0.5$\\

         5 & D7 &R& $0.6$ \\

         6 & D6 &NR&  \\

         7 &  D12 &NR& \\

         8 & D15 &NR& \\

         9 & D21 &R&$0.44$ \\

         10 & D9 &NR&  \\
          \hline
         \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Avg}} & $0.635$ \\
         \hline
        \end{tabular}
                        \hfill
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\

        \hline
         1 & D12 & R & $1.00$\\

         2 &  D1 & NR&\\

         3 & D3& NR& \\

         4 &  D5 &NR& \\

         5 & D7 &R& $0.4$ \\

         6 & D6 &R& $0.5$ \\

         7 &  D2 &NR& \\

         8 & D15 &NR& \\

         9 & D21 &NR& \\

         10 & D9 &NR&  \\
          \hline
         \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Avg}} & $0.633$ \\
         \hline
        \end{tabular}

        \end{table}
```

Comment: Please can you add the complete source and a picture also with your hand what would you to obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put each `tabular` in a `parbox`:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
    \parbox{.3 \textwidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
            1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
            2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{My first table}
        \label{tab:1}
    }
    \hfill
    \parbox{.3 \textwidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
            1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
            2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
            2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
            2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{My second table}
        \label{tab:2}
    }
    \hfill
    \parbox{.3 \textwidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
            1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
            2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{My third table}
        \label{tab:3}
    }
 \end{table}
```

[image]

This does, unfortunately, not align the tables vertically if they have different heights.

**Edit:**
As being pointed out by @Schweinebacke ad @Jan, you can align them using

```
\parbox[b]{.3 \textwidth}{
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}
    ...
```

[image]
Also, you should read @Jan's answer concerning better formatting of your document.

Comment: You could use the optional argument of `\parbox`: `[t]` as in **T**op or `[b]` as in **B**ottom, to align the boxes and its enclosed tables.  But you don't need to use the `\parbox` at all.  Just insert the `\tabular`-environment directly in the cell.

Comment: It worked, I appreciate it @jmb really thanks!!

Comment: @Jan I tried using `\parbox[t]{...}` or `\parbox[b]{...}`, but it didn't work for me, they just stayed the same. Is it possible that the `parbox` shrinks around its content making Top, Bottom and Middle basically the same?

Comment: Try `\parbox[t]{…}` and `\begin{tabular}[b]{…}`.

Comment: @Jan Not using any `parbox`es  doesn't work with captions and labels, I believe.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Ah, that works! I edited the post :)

Comment: @jmb see my MWE.  It surely works and I don't see any influence, it could/might/should have on `\caption` or `\label`.

Comment: @Jan Sorry, I meant individual labels/captions for each `tabular`.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding from your MWE, there is no second or third table, so I copied the existing one for two times, making three tables at all.

Nevertheless, you should use the `booktabs`-package and especially read its [manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/), as it explains the usage of lines in tables very well.  I added this package and replaced your lines by them.

Second: use the `array`-package, in order to be able to use some stuff, that comes in very handy.  Please also study the according [manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/array/).  I used the `\newcolumntype`-command, to define new columns, save typing efforts and especially, being able to change the table layout with one effort in the preamble.  I also used the `>{}` and `<{}` magic, to add an LaTeX-command, whenever you enter or leave a column, that those `>` and `<` are pointing at.

Third: Your last column contains math code.  Therefore you added `$`...`$` in your cells.  You can avoid that repeated typing, by placing the column into math mode by using the `>{$}c<{$}` as I stated above and in the example on the new column `C`.  But: in this special case, it makes a lot of sense, to use the `dcolumn`-package (read also that [manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn/)).  By using a `D`-column, you are able, to justify the numbers according to the decimal separator sign (in your case the `.`.  I defined the last column of the last table to be a `D`-column and its width according to 3 decimals.

Fourth: be careful, not to mix up the meaning of the `tabular` and the `table`-environment.  The first will produce something, that looks like a table.  The latter will produce something, that floats around, will be labeled with a table number and eventually be inserted in the List Of Tables.  Inside the `table`-environment, you should use at least one `tabular`-environment, to typeset some content, that will look like an ordinary table.

In order to produce the table number, use the `\caption`-command.  In order to reference that table in your text, use the `\label`- and `\ref`-commands.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% save typing work, by defining this new columntype to be four
%% "c"-columns at a batch.  Added "@{}" to prevent additional left and
%% right empty margins at the table.   As the las column is always in
%% math mode, use the >{$}c<{$} trick, to make this a math mode
%% column.  Use *{3} to have three identical centered columns also.
\newcolumntype{C}{@{} *{3}{c} >{$}c<{$} @{}}
%% Same as above, but in this case, we are using a dcolumn column as
%% the last column.   The D-column is automatically in math mode.  You
%% have to define, how many decimals you want to store in that
%% column.   The alignment is adjusted to the decimal sign, in this
%% case the ".".
%% As column identifier D is already in use by dcolumns package, I
%% defined this new column to be called by "B".
\newcolumntype{B}{@{} *{3}{c} D{.}{.}{3} @{}}


\begin{document}
%% Create an floating environment.  Floating tables use to have a
%% caption, which is placed above the table.  Use \label and \ref to
%% reference on that table.
\begin{table}
  \caption{Some tables next to each other}
  \label{tab:some-tables}
  %% decreasing the font size is a bad idea!  
   \footnotesize
   %% Begin the first table
   \begin{tabular}{C}           % New column type, declared above
     %% New horizontal rule
     \toprule
     %% The table head is not the major player!  Be gentle, use a
     %% font, that is not that offensive, as \textbf
     \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Search Results}} \\
     %% Again, the much nicer looking rule type
     \midrule
     1 & D7 & R & 1.00\\
     2 &  D2 & R&1.00\\
     3 & D3& NR& \\
     4 &  D5 &R& 0.75\\
     5 & D1 &R& 0.8 \\
     6 & D6 &NR&  \\
     7 &  D12 &R& 0.71\\
     8 & D15 &NR& \\
     9 & D21 &NR& \\
     10 & D9 &R& 0.6 \\
     \midrule
     \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Avg}} & 0.810 \\
     %% last of the cute new lines types
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \hfill
   %% Second table.   Cut and pasted from the table No. 1
   \begin{tabular}{C}
     \toprule
     \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Search Results}} \\
     \midrule
     1 & D7 & R & 1.00\\
     2 &  D2 & R&1.00\\
     3 & D3& NR& \\
     4 &  D5 &R& 0.75\\
     5 & D1 &R& 0.8 \\
     6 & D6 &NR&  \\
     7 &  D12 &R& 0.71\\
     8 & D15 &NR& \\
     9 & D21 &NR& \\
     10 & D9 &R& 0.6 \\
     \midrule
     \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Avg}} & 0.810 \\
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \hfill
   %% Third and last table, also C&P!
   \begin{tabular}{B}
     \toprule
     \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Search Results}} \\
     \midrule
     1 & D7 & R & 1.00\\
     2 &  D2 & R&1.00\\
     3 & D3& NR& \\
     4 &  D5 &R& 0.75\\
     5 & D1 &R& 0.8 \\
     6 & D6 &NR&  \\
     7 &  D12 &R& 0.71\\
     8 & D15 &NR& \\
     9 & D21 &NR& \\
     10 & D9 &R& 0.6 \\
     \midrule
     \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Avg}} & 0.810 \\
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

There are some tables next to each other, as presented in
table~\ref{tab:some-tables}. 
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Package [`threeparttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) can be used to set serveral table beside each other with well aligned captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
   \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
     1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{My first table}
   \label{tab:1}
 \end{threeparttable}
 \hfill
 \begin{threeparttable}
   \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
     1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{My second table}
   \label{tab:2}
 \end{threeparttable}
 \hfill
 \begin{threeparttable}
   \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
     1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{My third table}
   \label{tab:3}
 \end{threeparttable}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: caption below table]

It can be used also with usual captions above tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
   \caption{My first table}
   \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
     1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \label{tab:1}
 \end{threeparttable}
 \hfill
 \begin{threeparttable}
   \caption{My second table}
   \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
     1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \label{tab:2}
 \end{threeparttable}
 \hfill
 \begin{threeparttable}
   \caption{My third table}
   \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
     1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
     2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
     \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \label{tab:3}
 \end{threeparttable}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: caption above table]

If the tables are related you can use the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Three related tables}\label{tab:all}
  \subcaptionbox{My first table\label{tab:1}}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
      1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
      2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \subcaptionbox{My second table\label{tab:2}}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
      1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
      2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
      2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
      2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \subcaptionbox{My third table\label{tab:3}}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Search Results}} \\
      1 & D7 & R & $1.00$\\
      2 &  D2 & R&$1.00$\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: using subcaption]

Comment: This is a good answer especially regarding the subcaptions.

Comment: @Jan: Thanks. It could be better (using nice tables with `booktabs` like you've done), but I'm too lazy.

Comment: But it was nevertheless instructive!